# Grouping and summing using BigDecimal parallelly in java 8

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping, bigdecimal, collectors

I have a list of products with amount one of the attributes. And the list can contain common product name with other attributes being different. So i want to group the list by product and the sum of the amount of the products which share common name in java 8 using grouping and Summing.

```
Example:
[  
   {  
      "name":"Product A",
      "amount":"40.00",
      "description":"Info1",
      "number":"65"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Product A",
      "amount":"50.00",
      "description":"Info2",
      "number":"67"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Product A",
      "amount":"100.00",
      "description":"Info3",
      "number":"87"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Product B",
      "amount":"45.00",
      "description":"Info4",
      "number":"86"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Product D",
      "amount":"459.00",
      "description":"Info5",
      "number":"7"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Product B",
      "amount":"50.00",
      "description":"Info6",
      "number":"8"
   }
]
```

The output should be similar to this:

```
{  
   "Product A = 190.00":[  
      {  
         "name":"Product A",
         "amount":"40.00",
         "description":"Info1",
         "number":"65"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Product A",
         "amount":"50.00",
         "description":"Info2",
         "number":"67"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Product A",
         "amount":"100.00",
         "description":"Info3",
         "number":"87"
      }
   ],
   "Product B=95.00":[  
      {  
         "name":"Product B",
         "amount":"45.00",
         "description":"Info4",
         "number":"86"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Product B",
         "amount":"50.00",
         "description":"Info6",
         "number":"8"
      }
   ],
   "Product D = 459.00":[  
      {  
         "name":"Product D",
         "amount":"459.00",
         "description":"Info5",
         "number":"7"
      }
   ]
```

I have created a bean class `ProductBean` which have all the fields (name, amount, description and number) and getters and setters for the same.
And productBeans has list of all the products.

```
Map<String, List<ProductBean>> groupByProduct = 
               productBeans.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.getName()))

Map<String, BigDecimal> result = 
      productBeans.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ProductBean::getName, 
                                Collectors.mapping(ProductBean::getAmount, 
                     Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))));
```

groupByProduct has list of products grouped with name.
result gives the map of product as the key and total amount of that product as value.

But here i'm trying to map the product and total amount to the list of products. I tried to combine the above code to get the expected output but not able to achieve. And same has been achieved by iterating through the map.

But any help in merging the above code to get the map in which product name and amount as key and list as value would be helpful.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why your question isn't quite good: it seems you simply want someone to write code for you. You don't show any own attempt. You can likely be [downvoted](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) for this.

Comment: I did achieve through java 7 and in java 8 I could make it grouping and summing separately but not all in one operation for which I was trying to get suggestion on

Comment: @Padmini then show your attempt to better illustrate your description.

Comment: @Aominè Added the code as suggested. Please do let me know for any further info

Comment: Map<String, List<ProductBean>> groupByProduct = productBeans.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.getName()))
Map<String, BigDecimal> result = descriptionInfoBeans.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ProductBean::getName, 
                          Collectors.mapping(ProductBean::getAmount, Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))));

Comment: @Padmini where is `descriptionInfoBeans` coming from?

Comment: it's productBeans my mistake

Comment: Please do consider it as productBeans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want something as such of `Map<String, BigDecimal, List<ProductBean>>` where the String represents the `name`, the `BigDecimal` being the summation of all the Product's amount and `List<ProductBean>` being the list of products in that specific group.

such a map is not possible, so instead, you've managed to do it in two steps which is not very efficient and it doesn't keep related data together rather it separates it into two maps.

My suggestion is to create a wrapper class as such:

```
class ResultSet {

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public List<ProductBean> getProductBeans() {
        return productBeans;
    }

    public void setProductBeans(List<ProductBean> productBeans) {
        this.productBeans = productBeans;
    }

    private String name;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private List<ProductBean> productBeans;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ResultSet{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", amount=" + amount +
                ", productBeans=" + productBeans +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Which will wrap a given group of `ProductBean's` maintaining related data both for better maintainability and arguably readability.

Now, you can accomplish the task at hand with:

```
List<ResultSet> result = productList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ProductBean::getName))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> {
                    ResultSet resultSet = new ResultSet();
                    BigDecimal sum = e.getValue().stream()
                            .map(ProductBean::getAmount)
                            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
                    resultSet.setName(e.getKey());
                    resultSet.setAmount(sum);
                    resultSet.setProductBeans(e.getValue());
                    return resultSet;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This groups by the `ProductBean` name, and then maps each group, to a `ResultSet` instance which will encapsulate the name, summation of the amount in that specific group and the entire `ProductBean's` in the group.

You can further refactor the above stream query by creating a method for the mapping:

```
private static ResultSet mapToResultSet(Map.Entry<String, List<ProductBean>> e) {
        ResultSet resultSet = new ResultSet();
        BigDecimal sum = e.getValue().stream()
                .map(ProductBean::getAmount)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
        resultSet.setName(e.getKey());
        resultSet.setAmount(sum);
        resultSet.setProductBeans(e.getValue());
        return resultSet;
}
```

Thus, rendering the stream query to:

```
List<ResultSet> result = productList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ProductBean::getName))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(Main::mapToResultSet) // Main representing the class containing the mapToResultSet method
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *almost* got it.

`Collectors.groupingBy` allows a second parameter, which is a collector that will produce value for the key. You only need to pass your collector from the second line as this second parameter:

```
    Map<String, BigDecimal> result = productBeans
            .stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(ProductBean::getName,
                Collectors.mapping(ProductBean::getAmount, 
                    Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))));
```

Comment: I did try by passing second parameter. But no luck. Thanks @lexicore for ur response

Comment: @Padmini What do you mean by "no luck"?

Comment: I couldn't able to make it

Comment: @Padmini What happened when you have tried passing the second parameter?

Comment: @lexicore after grouping and mapping it yields `Map<String, BigDecimal>` which is good but the OP also wants to maintain all the `ProductBean`s in that specific group. something like `Map<String, BigDecimal, List<ProductBean>>` but that's not possible, I've provided an alternative to accomplish this in my answer if it helps clarify.

Comment: To complete your answer you can do: `productBeans.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ProductBean::getName))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()`

Comment: `.map(e -> {
                    BigDecimal sum =
                            e.getValue().stream()
                                    .map(ProductBean::getAmount)
                                    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
                    return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(),
                            new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(sum, e.getValue()));
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                        AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));`

Comment: this will yield a `Map<String, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<BigDecimal, List<ProductBean>>>` which is pretty much what the OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my previous answer which recommends creating a wrapper class. if for any reason one doesn't want to create a custom class *solely* to wrap the results, then another solution is as follows:

```
List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Map.Entry<String, List<ProductBean>>, BigDecimal>> 
         resultSet =
                productBeans.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ProductBean::getName))
                            .entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .map(Main::mapToSimpleEntry)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where `Main` is the class containing `mapToSimpleEntry` and `mapToSimpleEntry` is defined as:

```
private static AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Map.Entry<String, List<ProductBean>>, BigDecimal> mapToSimpleEntry(Map.Entry<String, List<ProductBean>> e) {
        BigDecimal sum =
                e.getValue().stream()
                        .map(ProductBean::getAmount)
                        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e, sum);
}
```

This solution has the advantage that:

1. one doesn't need to create a custom class
2. less code